# Bootstrap-select drop-down alignment breaks when live data search is enabled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap-select to add dropdown in my HTML form. When I enable the live data search option in the dropdown then it's alignment breaks.See the below pictures,

**Live data search enabled**

[image]

**Live data search not enabled**

[image]

**Here is my HTML code for dropdown**

```
<label for="emp_location">Location <sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <select name="emp_location" data-size="5" data-live-search="true"  data-container="body" id="location" class="form-control show-tick selectpicker" title="Choose one of the following...">
                                            <?php foreach ($locations as $location) : ?>
                                                <option value="<?= $location->id ?>" <?= !empty($emp) ? ($emp->location == $location->id ? 'selected' : '')  : '' ?>><?= $location->city_name ?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I haven't written any custom CSS for that. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No. I just removed the live search feature.